# Getting started with text service framework (TSF)?

Tags: text-services-framework

I am asking about a good resources and sample code for TSF?

Comment: Hi this is useful link in your requirement http://input.foruto.com/IME/Windows/IME_PROGRAMMING/TSF/index.html

Answer (score 1):

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/tsf

Answer (score 1):

http://blogs.msdn.com/tsfaware/default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The Windows SDK has a number of TSF samples in the samples/input directory.